# Saving projects including WMS files

Tags: save

How do I save a project so I can share it to others if the project also contains WMS files.

I know that all files have to be stored in the same location and then save the project file in the same folder, but I want to have the WMS files as well.

Comment: What do you mean by WMS files? WMS is a service and there is not much more to save than the http address of the service.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.